# Many mongo page faults when the query is covered by the index

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.runCommand({ "aggregate": "collection_name", "pipeline": [ { "$match": { "CompanyId": { "$gte": 720, "$lte": 740 } } }, { "$project": { "CompanyId": 1, "_id": 0} }, { "$group": { "_id": "$CompanyId", "total": { "$sum": 1 } } } ]})

db.collection_name.find({"CompanyId": {"$gte": 720, "$lte": 740}}, {"CompanyId": 1, "_id": 0})
```

Explain of second query

```
 {
   "cursor" : "BtreeCursor CompanyId_1",
   "isMultiKey" : false,
   "n" : 491699,
   "nscannedObjects" : 0,
   "nscanned" : 491699,
   "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
   "nscannedAllPlans" : 491699,
   "scanAndOrder" : false,
   "indexOnly" : true,
   "nYields" : 3841,
   "nChunkSkips" : 0,
   "millis" : 424,
   "indexBounds" : {
    "CompanyId" : [
        [
            720,
            740
        ]
    ]
},
"filterSet" : false
```

}

Query is covered by index, but has many nYields. Total size of mongo index is 700Mb. Server has 6GB Ram.

Agreggation query is slow(5-25 seconds) and mongostat show many page faults (700 page faults)
Even after run command, page faults same.

```
db.runCommand({ touch: "collection_name", index: true })
```

Please help to understand, how it can be. Aggregation query must be covered by index. Why so many page faults?

Comment: define index on CompanyId

Comment: Aggregation query is not covered, it will load the documents from disk. Currently the aggregation cannot use covered indexes

Comment: @Sammaye: though this comment is short, imho it is worth to be upgraded to an answer, maybe with a link to the docs.

Comment: `db.runCommand({ "aggregate": "collection_name", "pipeline": [ { "$match": { "CompanyId": { "$gte": 320, "$lte": 640 } } }, { "$project": { "CompanyId": 1, "_id": -1} } ]})`

@Sammaye: When this query executed monstat show many page faults too. So aggregation query framework cannot to analyze query and optimize them to use covered index. Did I understand u correctly?

Comment: @PashaKursa are you seeing many yields no matter how many times you run? It could be that readahead/ulimit settings might be a little off causing your data to not be cached quite right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This point does not directly answer your question about yields but it will answer the question of speed.

Even though you have a covered query it is good to note that MongoDB cannot use covered indexes in aggregation due to a regression.

Here is a list of tasks that apply to this limitation in 2.6+ (stable): https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12015?jql=project%20%3D%20SERVER%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22Aggregation%20Framework%22%20AND%20text%20~%20%22covered%20index%22 with the first one being the main problem.

As to the yeilds: there is a lack of informatin about the work load on your server among other things. It does not mean the query was slow; 491,699 documents scanned in 424 ms is not too bad wich could mean that your sever was experiencing load when you ran this query, it could also be that the data for the index was not in RAM at the time and so needed to be paged in, mongodb tends to yeild when data is being paged in to allow other operations to run and 700MB is a lot of pages.

More on yields can be found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/